# Recommended way to handle removing/renaming a realm model

Tags: react-native, realm

I am using realm with the react-native app I am currently working on. The problem I am facing right now is that I need to rename or delete an old model and migrate the data to a new model.

Everything works nicely after I create new models, but when I look at Realm Browser to see new data, I can still see data with the old removed model.
I tried deleteAll with realm before inserting new data, and it doesn't seem to remove data with old model.

E.g. the app used to have a model names `Car`, but now I want to be more specific with `Truck` and `Sedan`, etc. So I create the new models, remove the old model `Car`, but I can still see data with `Car` after launch.

I am wondering if there is a way to delete the stale data. I tried doing migration, but since the schema does not have the old model, realm cannot refer to the stale data to delete them.

Comment: Are you using Sync Realm or just non-sync db?

Comment: Just non-sync db. Right now I’m deleting .realm file to get what I want but I was wondering if there are better options.

Comment: Probably `compact()`.

Comment: Ahhh, looks like it’s gonna be in the next release. I’m assuming what it does is remove unnecessary data on the file? Which is exactly what I want.

Comment: ....wow I didn't realize they didn't have `compact()` exposed in the JS version until now! Ah well, I think I'll add that as the answer because that'll be the solution once it's out. Technically `compact()` removes the space left behind by deleted data.

Comment: Understood. Will give the master branch of the lib a try and see how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Realm.compact()` removes the space left behind by deletions. Compacting works if there are no open Realm instances.

This will be added to the API in the version that comes after 1.10.3.

Comment: Sorry to un-accept the answer, but it seems that this is not the solution to my problem. Since the data is stale, realm didn't try to remove it during compact. I can still see the data in Realm Browser.

Comment: It does remove the extra space when I delete my other data.

Comment: Wow. That's really strange. If Object Store manages the schema in the JS binding, then this is a bug in Object Store, if this is not a synchronized Realm. Sync Realms disallow destructive schema operations, and removed fields/classes are just hidden. That shouldn't be the case in non-sync realm afaik

Comment: In that case this is something you should ask on their Github issues.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I should look more into Sync Realm later to see if that's better suited for our need. I have created an issue on `realm-js`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, it probably isn't. I think your issue is https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1268, right? You don't seem to remove the class in the migration code from the schema, just delete the objects.

Comment: Hmm, I am using the synchronized way of initing realm, `new Realm({ schema: [...] });` and removed the model class from the array in the initialization.

Comment: It is sync realm if it is initialized as `new Realm({ sync: {`. If you do not have `sync { ... }` then it is not a synchronized Realm. In which case I'm not sure why it does not get deleted properly.

Comment: It does not have the `sync: {` config. Hmm, hopefully the js team has more insights on what I can do to solve this. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`realm-js` folks have exposed a method called `Realm.deleteModel` on Realm to delete model during migration. This should solve the problem of having stale data after migration when removing/renaming a model.

See https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1268 for more detail